# Best OpenSource/free solution for compiling in basic for Windows

Tags: basic

i need a tiny program like powerbasic for compiling basic applications that runs on the console of windows (tiny, so microsoft express edition is not an option). What do you recomend me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FreeBASIC is a free/open source (GPL), 32-bit BASIC compiler[1] for Microsoft Windows, protected-mode DOS (DOS extender), Linux, FreeBSD and Xbox.

http://freebasic.net

OS   DOS, FreeBSD, Linux, Microsoft Windows
License  GNU GPL, Standard libraries licensed under the GNU LGPL

Answer (score 5):

You can use Microsoft's Visual Basic compiler [from the command prompt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/380cz5k4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
vbc.exe Source.vb
```

The compiler is part of the .NET Framework installation and is located in

```
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<Framework version>\vbc.exe
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick Basic compiler link I found using search:

http://www.qbcafe.net/qbc/english/download/compiler/qbasic_compiler.shtml

Answer (score 2):

There's a qbasic version still in development at http://www.qbasic.com/

Answer (score 2):

QBasic http://www.qbcafe.net/qbc/english/download/compiler/qbasic_compiler.shtml
Best BASIC programming environment ever in my opinion (VisualBasic and Real Basic don't count but they are equally awesome)

Answer (score 1):

And then there is XBasic

XBasic is a variant of the BASIC programming language

http://xbasic.sourceforge.net/

Both mentioned FOSS variants can compile for Windows

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

JustBasic is free, small, and wonderful!  And the users in the forums are extremely friendly and helpful!  http://www.justbasic.com  (I'm not sure if it's open source though... but it IS free)

Answer (score 1):

I use QB64 a 64-bit compiler for Windows XP 7 8. Compiles most (or easily converted) QuickBasic 4.5 programs.

Comment: I meant to say QuickBasic 4.5 and on.